# onCreate() is not overridden when extending Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this code:

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

I know that when creating fragment, you separately implement `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`. However, `onCreate()` is obviously missing here.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` can be overridden by you.

- `onCreate()` is more optional and you can use to instantiate some variables (but you hardly need to override it).
- `onCreateView()` is mandatory since you must inflate the view that you want and return it (like `return view;`).

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> onCreate()
>   The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.
>   
> onCreateView()
>   The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

You can also check the Fragment Life Cycle.

As you can see in picture below, in case of returning from back stack, only `onCreateView()` is called again... So, you can use `onCreate()` to run some code that can be executed only once (when Fragment is created... like configure some array or something like that)...

Then, you leave `onCreateView()` just to refresh/inflate the Views before displaying it to the user.

But again: `onCreate()` is not usually overriden and there's no problem with that... Is always up to you...

[image]:

Answer (score 1):

> you separately call onCreate() and onCreateView()

No, *you* don't call either. The [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png) calls them.

---

`onCreate` is not needed to be implemented on a simple `Fragment` class, only `Activity` classes

As for the title of your question - it should be called if you add that Fragment to an Activity.

Comment: i have this other activity, and inside it I really do have onCreate() method, but inside that method I have variable definition:
otherActivity{
onCreate(){
customMadeClass c = new customMadeClass();
}}
is it only because that 'c' variable that I have onCreate() there ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I said, Activity's do need the `onCreate` with a `setContentView`... the `inflate.inflate` of the `Fragment` is the equivalent of that